# differentiate in differential operator

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

i was stuck at this when solve differential equation using differential operator,,i didnt know whether this means differentiate the differential operator(?).
 $y_p=\frac{1}{(D-1)(D-2)^3}e^{2x}$=$x\frac{1}{(D−2)^2(4D−5)}e^{2x}$ 
$L(D) \rightarrow L'(D)$ $(D−1)(D−2)^3  \rightarrow **(D−2)^2(4D−5)**$ i didnt understand the star part. and the star part is the answer, i would appreciate if someone can give me a hint thanks!!

Comment: Here's how you draw arrows: `\to \rightarrow \Rightarrow \longrightarrow \leftarrow` $\to \rightarrow \Rightarrow \longrightarrow \leftarrow$ and there are other variations.

Comment: Can you please give more details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this. Let
‎$$a_ny^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_2y''+a_1y'+a_0y=r(x)$$‎
with constant coefficients. With ‎$D$‎ operator
‎$$a_nD^ny+a_{n-1}D^{n-1}y+\cdots+a_2D^2y+a_1Dy+a_0y=r(x)$$‎
so
‎$$y=\frac{1}{F(D)}r(x)$$‎
where
‎$$F(D)=a_nD^n+a_{n-1}D^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2D^2+a_1D+a_0$$‎
in special case when the right side is of the form $x~r(x)$ we can use following shortcut
‎$$y_p=\frac{1}{F(D)}x.r(x)=x\frac{1}{F(D)}r(x)-\frac{F^\prime(D)}{F^2(D)}r(x)$$‎

Comment: thankyou, im not sure though, but it is special case when substitute the 2 from $e^2x$ to the $F(D) $ and the result is zero, so it become like that (differentiate) (?)